# Hibernate session-per-request vs session-per-operation pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, session

I was reading about session & transaction from [Sessions and transactions](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions) wiki page. Inside the context of **The scope of a unit of work** I read about **session implementation patterns** namely 
*Session-per-request*, *Session-per-operation*, *Session-per-request-with-detached-objects* & *Session-per-conversation*.

As *I don't have deep knowledge of Hibernate*, I have some queries on this.

- I didn't understand what is the difference between them ?
- In which condition they are applicable ?
- Can anybody give real life examples of using these patterns ?

Thank You

Comment: Hibernate reference manual [Session and transaction scopes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-basics) and Hibernate developers guide [Transactional patterns (and anti-patterns)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d5e728) - no easy reads but most information is there.